# Is there a way to apply SAS EG processes to new files?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm taking over a project from a coworker that involves several extensive SAS process flows. I have all the files with all the same names and a copy of the process flows they used. Since the file paths in their processes are direct references to their computer, normally I would just re-import the files with the same output names and run the process from there. In a few cases I would have to recreate a query builder as I'm using a few .sas7bdat files from another project.

However, there are quite a few files involved and I may end up having to pass this to another coworker in a few months, and since I can't get a good look at exactly what the import task is doing I'm concerned I may have some of the variables imported incorrectly. Is there an easy way to just change the file path the import or other task refers to?

Comment: Do you have the option of converting the non-code modules to SAS code?  Also, can you run things from a network share instead of from your local computer?

Comment: That's a good point about converting to code - if that's the best option available I'll  do that so my coworkers don't have to go through this process during the handoff. However, I'm still hoping for something that will let me edit the tasks directly so I don't have to convert like 50 input files. I can't run it off a share drive because some of the source files contain information not authorized for that level of security, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting, at my organization data with higher levels of security are required to be on shared drives (and not on personal computers)...  how is this structured?  Is there a folder, like, c:\myproject\mysasprograms.egp , and then the data is in c:\myproject\data\ or something?

Comment: The data is stored on a system that connects us directly with the data collection source, but because we have a limited number of licenses only a few team members access it directly. So my SAS flow is stored on my personal computer, data is compiled on the system and sent to me directly, and my analysis results are sent to my supervisor. My SAS processes without data are backed up on the share drive once a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

Given the updates in comments, there's two possibilities I see.

1. If the paths you're changing are, or can be, relative to the location of the EGP, then you can right click on the Project->Properties->File References and check "Use paths relative to the project...", which means instead of storing a file in `c:\my EGP folder\my code folder\code.sas` it would store it as `my code folder\code.sas`.  So then if the whole project moves to another computer (or just any other folder) then it automatically has the right path.  This is mostly useful for code or similar things.
2. Otherwise, you're going to have to convert things to SAS code modules.  There you can use macro variables to define the locations of things.

Comment: Thanks Joe. The site won't let me upvote your answer since I don't have enough reputation, but the first option appears to work for me. :)